# Can we differentiate between observed sequences of IID and uncorrelated noise?

Tags: noise

Given a realization $\{z_{i}\}_{i}$ of some noise process $\{Z_{i}\}_{i}$ that is either a White-Noise process or an IID process, i.e. both are uncorrelated however the former also is independent, can we determine which one it is?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The title is about generation; the first paragraph is about sampling; the second paragraph is about inference. It's hard to tell what you're actually asking.

Comment: Yes! What I mean by generating is sampling, I should have said that instead. I want to sample say $\hat{X}_{i}\sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\tilde{X}_{i}\sim IID(0,\sigma^2)$, where WN and IID denote White Noise and Independent and Identically Distributed (noise). In the Gaussian case these two overlap, but in other cases? Can we actually see from data if a realization of noise, i.e. a sequence of noise observations, is IID or WN, assuming it is not Gaussian? @MBaz

Comment: Please clarify by **editing** your question; also, you seem to know exactly that independentend and zero mean is stronger than white, so what's the question here?

Comment: @MarcusMüller My question is: given an observerd sequence of noise variables, can you ever determine between if they are IID or WN? The only difference between IID and WN, to my knowledge, is that the former are independent (which implies uncorrelated) and the latter only uncorrelated. Is there anyway to distinguish if an uncorrelated sequence of noise variables also är independent? I guess this is another formulation of what I am trying to ask.

Comment: **edit** your question to clarify. And please ask only **one** formulation. Because: they are not the same question (we can address the differences in separate questions, but it's hard enough to answer one of your four different questions you ask here.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Done! I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem with Problem statement

Strictly speaking, every IID noise (as long as zero-mean) is uncorrelated. So, there's no "difference"; IID is a special case of uncorrelated. But we can ask ourselves:

> Can we tell uncrorellated noise  that is  IID from uncorrelated noise that's not IID?

And the answer is yes. You "simply" have to prove that either:

1. the distribution is not identical for all times, or
2. that the distributions are not jointly independent.

## Examples of where we might meet these

To give examples in hopes of illustrating the issue:

### Non-identically distributed, but uncorrelated

Let the discrete-time random process $X_i$ follow

$$X_i \sim \begin{cases}
    \mathcal N(0,1) & \text{ for } i=2N\\
    \mathcal N(0,2) & \text{ for } i=2N+1\\
\end{cases},
N\in \mathbb N, \text{ independent for different $i$,}
$$

then the process looks white (is uncorrelated), because, although not stationary, the autocorrelation is zero for any non-zero lag. You've violated the identicality.

### Dependent, but uncorrelated (in the pair-wise sense)

Also, $Y_i$ be a discrete time process. Define:

$$Y_i \begin{cases}
\sim U\{-1,+1\} &\text{randomly, independently}&  \text{ for }i \ne 3N,\\
=Y_{i-1}\cdot Y_{i-2} &\text{(fixed!)} & \text{ for }i=3N
\end{cases}.$$

Clearly, all the $Y_i$  have $P(Y_i= -1)=P(Y_i= +1)=0.5$, but also clearly, every third $Y_i$ fully depends on its previous two.

## Detection

How to detect this?

### non-identicality

First of all, just write down all $f_{X_i}(x)$ for all $i$. If you can find a single one that's not like the others, you've disproven IID.
Sadly, that's not necessarily enough, so you need to generally show that $f_{X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \ldots}(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ are the same for all time sequences $\vec i=(i_1, i_2,\ldots)$ (which don't even have to be finite in length, far as I can tell).

In other words, to *prove* your process can be IID, you need to prove $f_{X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \ldots}(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ is constant, no matter how choose your $\vec i$.

### Dependence

You need to show that for every possible $\vec i$, $f_{X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \ldots}(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = \prod\limits_{n\in\vec i}f_{X_n}(x_n)$.

([this is even stricter than pair-wise independence, and it's a common pitfall for people who think uncorrelated + Gaussian == independend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent)). If you can't prove that, the noise might not be IID!

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer Marcus. Very nice examples. So in order to investigate dependence we must know all joint distributions and all marginal distributions. I guess this is never done in practice then? Maybe there is no reason anyway.

Comment: well, often things become quite a bit easier – for example, if you can bound the size of "memory" something can have, or will care about. On the transmitting site, an interleaver makes adjacent things look independent, and if your receiver only "cares" about independence within a small window: jay!

Comment: Given a _sequence_ of real numbers $(z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_n)$ constituting an alleged sample of white noise or whatever, _how_ on earth does one write down the the distributions of the underlying random variables? In fact, even earlier in this answer, given a _sequence_ of real numbers $(z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_n)$ constituting an alleged sample of white noise or whatever, how does one _know_ that the even-numbered samples are realizations of $N(0,1)$ random variables while the odd-numbered samples are realizations of $N(0,2)$ random variables? These are _assumptions_ that (continued)...

Comment: ... (continued)... that are totally unsupported by any evidence, certainly not by anything that can be deduced from the data. In your rush to answer, you have made far too many claims that you might wish to withdraw after more deliberation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what exactly the OP understands or means by the various words in the phrase

> either a White-Noise process or an IID process, i.e. both are uncorrelated however the former also is independent,

For example, the initialism IID usually stands for "**independent** *identically distributed*", and so "IID process" *usually* means a sequence of **independent** *identically distributed* random variables. If readers agree that this is the accepted meaning, then the OP's statement that the random variables constituting the process are uncorrelated is perfectly true, but the very next words "former *also* (emphasis added) is independent" suggests that the OP thinks that the random variables constituting the IID process are *not* independent, uncorrelated though they happen to be. Of course, those who *don't* accept the generally accepted meaning of IID will have their own version of what is the truth and what is a BIG LIE.

Similarly, it is not clear *what* the OP understands by "White-Noise process", except that the random variables constituting the process are independent random variables (and hence uncorrelated random variables). Are there any *other* requirements that might be reasonable to impose on the random variables constituting the White-Noise process? Zero mean, maybe? Symmetric distribution about $0$? Identical Distribution? or is something like $X[n] \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ for even $n$ and $X[n] \sim \mathcal N(0,2)$  for odd $n$ acceptable? And if so, what is the justification for this belief about the properties of a White Noise process?

There is a long-standing tradition on dsp.SE to say that (discrete-time) white noise is nothing more than a sequence of *uncorrelated* random variables and that independence is *not* required, and should not be insisted upon. I disagree with this school of thought because (i) correlation is a *pairwise* relation whereas independence is a more general property involving more than two random variables and (ii) lack of correlation only tells us that *linear* estimation/prediction is not useful but says *nothing* about more general *nonlinear* estimators/predictors.  A canonical example is of $X 
\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $Y = X^2$ which are uncorrelated random variables and yet $Y$ is a (nonlinear) function of $X$. As another example. consider the following from @MarcusMuller's answer to this question:

> ### Dependent, but uncorrelated (in the pair-wise sense)
>
> Also, $Y_i$ be a discrete time process. Define:
>
> $$Y_i \begin{cases}
> >\sim U\{-1,+1\} &\text{randomly, independently}&  \text{ for }i \ne 3N,\\
> >=Y_{i-1}\cdot Y_{i-2} &\text{(fixed!)} & \text{ for }i=3N
> >\end{cases}.$$

Indeed, $Y_1, Y_2,$ and $Y_3 = Y_1Y_2$ uncorrelated random variables, but in fact, $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are *pairwise* **independent** random variables too.  However, $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are not *mutually* independent random variables.